# Show that $G_i/G_{i+1} \twoheadrightarrow (G_i +N)/ (G_{i+1} +N)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

From Aluffi's book of Algebra:

[image]

in which it refers to Theorem 7.12 :

[image]

**[Red underlined:]** I can't see any connection with Theorem 7.12! Actually I don't know how the $+$ appears. How to show that $G_i/G_{i+1} \twoheadrightarrow (G_i +N)/ (G_{i+1} +N)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $G$ is understood to be a multiplicative group, I think the $+$ is a typo.
Let $G'=(G_iN)/(G_{i+1}N)$ and
\begin{align}
&\varphi:G_i\twoheadrightarrow G'&
&x\mapsto xG_{i+1}N
\end{align}
Since $G_{i+1}\subseteq\operatorname{Ker}\varphi$, theorem 7.12 asserts that there exists one and only one group homomorphism $\bar\varphi:G_i/G_{i+1}\to G'$ making the following diagram commutative:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
G_i@>\varphi>>G'\\
@V\pi VV @|\\
G_i/G_{i+1}@>>\bar\varphi>G'
\end{CD}
where $\pi:G_i\to G_i/G_{i+1}$ is the canonical projection onto the factor group.
Since $\varphi$ is surjective, $\bar\varphi$ is surjective as well.

If $G_i/G_{i+1} $ is simple, then $\operatorname{Ker}\bar\varphi=\{1\} $ or $\operatorname{Ker}\bar\varphi=G_i/G_{i+1} $, hence $\bar\varphi $ is an isomorphism or is trivial.

Comment: Why surjectivity of $\bar\varphi$ implies $G'$ is either trivial or
isomorphic to $G_i/G_{i+1}$? I can't figure that out even knowing $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is simple.

Comment: If $G_i/G_{i+1} $ is simple, then $\operatorname{Ker}\bar\varphi=\{1\} $ or $\operatorname{Ker}\bar\varphi=G_i/G_{i+1} $.